# I need onclick to stop after 500 collects or how ever many i tell it to

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is basically a link repeater and i cant figure out how to get it to stop after a number i want it to. Say i want it to repeat a link 500 times and then i would like it to stop. Is this possible? Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var a=0;
        var milli;
        function collect1()
        {
            var milli = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
            var links=document.getElementById('linkholder').value;
            links = links.replace(/[\n\r]/gi , " ");
            var link=links.split(" ",100000);
            var iframe1=document.getElementById('iframe1');
            iframe1.onload = function(){setTimeout(collect1, milli);};
            iframe1.src=link[a];
            a++;
            var count1=document.getElementById('count1');
            count1.innerHTML='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+a+' Collected';
            if (a >= link.length){a=0;}
        }
        function refreshgifts(){
        var invurl = document.getElementById('invurl').value;
        var iframeg=document.getElementById('inventory');
        iframeg.src = invurl;}
    function refreshinv(){
    var gifturl = document.getElementById('gifturl').value;
    var iframei=document.getElementById('stash');
    iframei.src = gifturl;}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="linkholder" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea></br>
<input id="numbers" type="number" value="1000"></input>
<button onclick="collect1();">Start</button>
    <div><div id="count1">0 Collected</div><iframe id="iframe1" src=""  style="width:700px;height:80px;" onload=""></iframe></div>

</br></br>
<button onclick="refreshgifts();">Refresh Gifts</button><input type="text"  style="overflow:hidden;" id="invurl"></input>
    <div><iframe id="inventory" src="" style="width:600px;height:200px;" onload=""></iframe></div>
<button onclick="refreshinv();">Refresh Stash</button><input type="text" style="overflow:hidden;" id="gifturl" ></input>
    <div><iframe id="stash" src="" style="width:600px;height:200px;" onload=""></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post the code not a picture

Comment: Since javascript variables are stored per client you will need to source the click-counter from the server.

Comment: @Gerald You just copy and paste it into your question. I started with Notepad myself  (ahh the days), but you may want to upgrade to something like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ;)

Comment: Hi, Please do not deface your post after you have taken help from it. It is like cutting down a tree after taking shelter below it. Please allow the other future users to gain from the knowledge. The answerer would have put a lot of effort. Do not put their valuable time to waste.

Comment: A moderator will soon come and lock the question. Why do continue to do that?

Comment: Its a hacking tool and i want my name no where near it. I did not know before i posted this. I want it gone or I will contact my lawyer about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var a=0,b=0;
            var milli;
          var cnt=1;
            function collect1()
            {
                var milli = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
                var links=document.getElementById('linkholder').value;
                var maxtimes=document.getElementById("maxtimes").value;
                var count1=document.getElementById('count1');
                links = links.replace(/[\n\r]/gi , " ");
                var link=links.split(" ",100000);
                var iframe1=document.getElementById('iframe1');
                //iframe1.onload = function(){setTimeout(collect1, milli);};
                iframe1.onload = function(){
                if(cnt<maxtimes) //maximum number that you wanted has to go here
                setTimeout(
                   function(){
                      collect1();
                      //count1.innerHTML+=" /"+cnt+" time(s), it run";
                      cnt++;
                   }, milli)
                else cnt=1;
                }
                iframe1.src=link[a];
                a++;b++;
                count1.innerHTML='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+a+' Collected'+" /"+b+" time(s), it run";;
                if (a >= link.length){a=0;}
            }
            function refreshgifts(){
            var invurl = document.getElementById('invurl').value;
            var iframeg=document.getElementById('inventory');
            iframeg.src = invurl;}
        function refreshinv(){
        var gifturl = document.getElementById('gifturl').value;
        var iframei=document.getElementById('stash');
        iframei.src = gifturl;}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea id="linkholder" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea></br>
    <input id="numbers" type="number" value="1000"></input>
    Number of Times:<input id="maxtimes" type="number" value="500"></input>
    <button onclick="collect1();">Start</button>
        <div><div id="count1">0 Collected</div><iframe id="iframe1" src=""  style="width:700px;height:80px;" onload=""></iframe></div>

    </br></br>
    <button onclick="refreshgifts();">Refresh Gifts</button><input type="text"  style="overflow:hidden;" id="invurl"></input>
        <div><iframe id="inventory" src="" style="width:600px;height:200px;" onload=""></iframe></div>
    <button onclick="refreshinv();">Refresh Stash</button><input type="text" style="overflow:hidden;" id="gifturl" ></input>
        <div><iframe id="stash" src="" style="width:600px;height:200px;" onload=""></iframe></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: edited the full code, can you please try with this.

Comment: I edited the original answer, please copy the code again and try it.

Comment: You can again copy the original code.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.